# Linux sed command to add text between first 2 |

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Want to add text after the `|` that comes after `TAPE`

```
Nigeria,IP,Nodetype,SITE,nodename,OK|BACKUP|Site|**TAPE**|Daily||**19-Oct-20**|,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,OK|ZK_bkp|/var/backup/path|Node|Daily||19-Oct-20|,NA,NA
```

Trying this `sed 's/TAPE|.*|.*|/&LAPE/g'`

but it adds the string after the last `|`

Comment: When you use `.*` it's greedy and matches as much as it can. Use `[^|]*` instead if you only want it to match non-pipe characters.

Comment: (that's an analogue to how the linked duplicate is trying to avoid matching to the last `/`, just as you're trying to avoid matching to the last `|`; same underlying problem, same solution).